# Print named range for dynamic formula evaluation - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I've been trying to determine an easy way to display the members of a named range as a columnar print, one per field. I'm building a timesheet application with worksheets for each month. The various available projects for staff to claim are in the named range. The range is used for field validation already, but I'd like to be able to list them on each worksheet to summarize the hours dedicated to the projects per employee.

```
Example: Named Range: Colors
Members: Red, Yellow, Blue, Orange, Green, Purple
Desired: Print the members of Colors in cells B20:B25
```

Comment: Are you aware you can access each member of the named range using the `INDEX` function? `=INDEX(Colors,1)` will give you `Red` and so on...

Comment: @CallumDA just like my answer, sweet, I must have gotten it correct. 8P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Colors` is a one dimensional array, either horizontal or vertical,Put this in B20, and drag down:

```
=INDEX(Colors,ROW(1:1))
```

If it is a two dimensional array then:

```
=INDEX(Colors,ROW(1:1),COLUMN(A:A))
```

Comment: That was perfect! Problem solved and a dozen thank you's!